# How to create an array and fill from tree node variable

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, tree, itext

I'm trying to transfer data from a treenode (at least I think that's what it is) which contains much more data than I need. It would be very difficult for me to manipulate the data within the treenode. I would much rather have an array which provides me with only the necessary data for data manipulation.

I would like higher rates have following variables:
1. BookmarkNumber (integer)
2. Date (string)
3. DocumentType (string)
4. BookmarkPageNumberString (string)
5. BookmarkPageNumberInteger (integer)

I would like to the above defined rate from the data from variable book_mark (as can be seen in my code).

I've been wrestling with this for two days. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm probably sure that the question wasn't phrased correctly so please ask questions so that I may explain further if needed.

Thanks so much

BTW what I'm trying to do is create a Windows Form program which parses a PDF file which has multiple bookmarks into discrete PDF files for each bookmark/chapter while saving the bookmark in the correct folder with the correct naming convention, the folder and naming convention dependent upon the PDF name and title name of the bookmark/chapter being parsed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using itextsharp.pdfa;
using iTextSharp.awt;
using iTextSharp.testutils;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.xmp;
using iTextSharp.xtra;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ChooseImageFileWrapper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = GlobalVariables.InitialDirectory;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Image File Wrapper Chooser";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    GlobalVariables.ImageFileWrapperPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            ImageFileWrapperPath.Text = GlobalVariables.ImageFileWrapperPath;
        }

        private void ImageFileWrapperPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(GlobalVariables.ImageFileWrapperPath);
            IList<Dictionary<string, object>> book_mark = iTextSharp.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);

            List<ImageFileWrapperBookmarks> IFWBookmarks = new List<ImageFileWrapperBookmarks>();
            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> bk in book_mark) // bk is a single instance of book_mark
            {
                ImageFileWrapperBookmarks.BookmarkNumber = ImageFileWrapperBookmarks.BookmarkNumber + 1;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvr in bk) // kvr is the key/value in bk
                {
                    if (kvr.Key == "Kids" || kvr.Key == "kids")
                    {
                        //create recursive program for children
                    }
                    else if (kvr.Key == "Title" || kvr.Key == "title")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (kvr.Key == "Page" || kvr.Key == "page")
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(GlobalVariables.ImageFileWrapperPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to parse a PDF and create a data structure similar to what you describe. First the data structure:

```
public class BookMark
{
    static int _number;
    public BookMark() { Number = ++_number; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PageNumberString { get; set; }
    public int PageNumberInteger { get; set; }
    public static void ResetNumber() { _number = 0; }

    // bookmarks title may have illegal filename character(s)
    public string GetFileName()
    {
        var fileTitle = Regex.Replace(
            Regex.Replace(Title, @"\s+", "-"), 
            @"[^-\w]", ""
        );
        return string.Format("{0:D4}-{1}.pdf", Number, fileTitle);
    }
}
```

A method to create a list of `Bookmark` (above):

```
List<BookMark> ParseBookMarks(IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks)
{
    int page;
    var result = new List<BookMark>();
    foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
    {
        // add top-level bookmarks
        var stringPage = bookmark["Page"].ToString();
        if (Int32.TryParse(stringPage.Split()[0], out page))
        {
            result.Add(new BookMark() {
                Title = bookmark["Title"].ToString(),
                PageNumberString = stringPage,
                PageNumberInteger = page
            });
        }

        // recurse
        if (bookmark.ContainsKey("Kids"))
        {
            var kids = bookmark["Kids"] as IList<Dictionary<string, object>>;
            if (kids != null && kids.Count > 0)
            {
                result.AddRange(ParseBookMarks(kids));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call method above like this to dump the results to a text file:

```
void DumpResults(string path)
{
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        // need this call to parse page numbers
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

        var bookmarks = ParseBookMarks(SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format(
                "{0, -4}{1, -100}{2, -25}{3}",
                bookmark.Number, bookmark.Title,
                bookmark.PageNumberString, bookmark.PageNumberInteger
            ));
        }
        File.WriteAllText(outputTextFile, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

The bigger problem is how to extract each `Bookmark` into a separate file. If **every** `Bookmark` **starts** a new page it's easy:

1. Iterate over the return value of `ParseBookMarks()`
2. Select a page range that begins with the current `BookMark.Number`, and ends with the *next* `BookMark.Number - 1`
3. Use that page range to create separate files.

Something like this:

```
void ProcessPdf(string path)
{
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        // need this call to parse page numbers
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

        var bookmarks = ParseBookMarks(SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader));
        for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.Count; ++i)
        {
            int page = bookmarks[i].PageNumberInteger;
            int nextPage = i + 1 < bookmarks.Count
                // if not top of page will be missing content
                ? bookmarks[i + 1].PageNumberInteger - 1 

                /* alternative is to potentially add redundant content:
                ? bookmarks[i + 1].PageNumberInteger
                */

                : reader.NumberOfPages;
            string range = string.Format("{0}-{1}", page, nextPage);

            // DEMO!
            if (i < 10)
            {
                var outputPath = Path.Combine(OUTPUT_DIR, bookmarks[i].GetFileName());
                using (var readerCopy = new PdfReader(reader))
                {
                    var number = bookmarks[i].Number;
                    readerCopy.SelectPages(range);
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (var document = new Document())
                        {
                            using (var copy = new PdfCopy(document, stream))
                            {
                                document.Open();
                                int n = readerCopy.NumberOfPages;
                                for (int j = 0; j < n; )
                                {
                                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(readerCopy, ++j));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's highly unlikely all bookmarks are going to be at the top of every page of the PDF. To see what I mean, experiment with commenting / uncommenting the `bookmarks[i + 1].PageNumberInteger` lines.